# implement impersonate in symfony2 without editing security.yml

Tags: symfony, impersonation

I want to implement impersonate in symfony2 without editing `security.yml` file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this is needed, but if it is I'd take a look at how the SecurityBundle achieves this functionality and implement my own version.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/SwitchUserListener.php

Create your own kernel listener that mimics this functionality with your own custom entry point.